# Xamarin forms Map is not getting my location

Tags: c#, google-maps, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a maps app but when I test my code it always gets my location like longitude = 0 lat = 0

I don't see anything wrong in my code, could you help me, please

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;


            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromTicks(10000));
            Position local = new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
            var reLocate = new Button { Text = "Re-center" };
            reLocate.Clicked += (sender, e) => { map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(local, Distance.FromMiles(0.5))); };

            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,                
                Label = "Tu Ubicación",
                Address = "A donde inicia la aventura"
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);


        }
```

[image]

Comment: I have added an answer, also make sure that your emulator has GPS enable

Comment: Did you add [Permissions & Additional Setup Considerations](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html) as mentioned in the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the location like this with the [Geolocator Plugin](http://Xam.Plugin.Geolocator):

```
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000), null, true);
```

---

if this doesn't work, i sugest you to use the Xamarin.Essentials for this (even in the [documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin), they advise you to do so)

And with [Xamarin.Essentials Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) you can get the location like this:

```
try
{
    var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
    var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

    if (location != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
    }
}
catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
{
    // Handle not supported on device exception
}
catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
{
    // Handle not enabled on device exception
}
catch (PermissionException pEx)
{
    // Handle permission exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Unable to get location
}
```

And you can even get the last known location to prevent doing a full query of the location each time:

`var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();`

---

Also don't forget to add the the needed Permissions on your Android Manifest

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```